Who first considered "Pascal Triangle"?
Arnold was used saying in his talks,
"Pascal’s triangle, so called, because it was by Chinese discovered"!
How much is he right?

"The triangle is named for Blaise Pascal – however, possibly the earliest discovery of the triangle was by the Islamic mathematician Abu Bekr ibn Muhammad ibn al-Husayn Al-Karaji who was born in Baghdad, Persia – now Iraq – in 953. The Chinese mathematician Jia Xian (~1010-1070) produced his version approximately 500 years before Pascal was born." source

Interesting question, but would be much better placed on History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchange rather than here.

I am an older user https://mathoverflow.net/users/34304/al-amrani  Please murge all my accounts. Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to HSM exchange

There is reason to attribute Pascal's triangle to Pingala in the second century B.C.E. See https://web.northeastern.edu/shah/papers/Pingala.pdf for instance.

@Al-Amrani As to account merge, the proper procedure is to contact the CMs via the contact form.
